# MacBook trackpad fires left and right click events when two-finger clicking in Windows

Tags: windows, macbook, boot-camp, touchpad, right-click

I bought a new MacBook Pro - it is awesome. I love Windows 7, and it *flies* on this hardware. However, I have one issue - two-finger right clicks fire both left and right click events.

So I used to have an older model MacBook Pro, with a one-button multitouch trackpad. In order to right-click, you just use two fingers while you press the button - viola, right-click.

This new fancy-ass MacBook has a trackpad with *no* buttons - the whole thing presses down. It works pretty well, but it'll take some getting used to. To right click, same deal, just use two fingers, and press down.

However, when you did the two-finger click on the new trackpad, it fires a right mouse click event as I press down, and then a left mouse click event when I release. This means that if I select text and right-click it, the text is deselected.

It only affects Windows, MacOS works fine. I'm running the latest Bootcamp drivers as provided by Apple. This only affects two-finger right clicking on the trackpad. External mice right-click correctly, and only one event is fired.

Comment: No offense but the first and second sentence is totally opposite. :D:D

Comment: Love Mac hardware, hate MacOS :)